# Where clause seems not to be working

Tags: mysql, sql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a590dd/1

I was trying to get a condition WHERE above the LIMIT clause, I wanted to make a `WHERE z.zlec_nr LIKE '%UA%'` but it's not working - its also not working when I put `WHERE z.zlec_nr = 'UAL25FND7BJ`'

```
SELECT zlec_status.nazwa                       AS Status, 
       piorytet.nazwa                          AS Priorytet, 
       Concat(koord.imie, ' ', koord.nazwisko) AS `Koordynator`, 
       Concat(zlec_adresy.miasto, ' - ', zlec_adresy.ulica, ' ', 
       zlec_adresy.oddzial) 
                                               AS `adres`, 
       zlec_z_dnia,zlec_id, 
       zlec_nr, 
       zlec_do, 
       zlec_ogran, 
       awizacje, 
       awizacja_na_dzien, 
       termin_zamkniecia, 
       tresc, 
       uwagi 
FROM   zlec z
       INNER JOIN koord 
               ON z.koord = koord.id 
       INNER JOIN zlec_adresy 
               ON z.zlec_addres = zlec_adresy.id 
       INNER JOIN piorytet 
               ON z.priorytet = piorytet.id 
       INNER JOIN zlec_status 
               ON z.status_zlecenia = zlec_status.id 
LIMIT 1, 2
```

I got no idea why the where statement doesn't want to work - the sql fiddle seems not to be working don't know why but on my localhost the query above executes normally and shows all whats needed, but the where statement seems not to be working, could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have no table with an alias of `z`. Should `z.zlec_nr` be `zlec.zlec_nr`?

Comment: I copied the old code, now its with alias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Everything works fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a590dd/8), your are just cutting off result with the `limit` clause. There is one row in the result set and you've set `offset` to 1, so your query returns nothing.

Comment: Wow:) Hehe thought its something small